Switch Module on a Router


I have configured spanning tree on switch A.
I can show the spanning tree and it is running on switch A
The 2 interface does not form an etherchannel, they are individual port
There are no broadcast storm, they work just fine
The root is on switch A
There is no manual blocking on any of the interface
The router module is 4221,module card is NIM-ES2-4

Why there are no spanning tree on the router module ?
Is the spanning tree protocol running on the interface ?
Why is it not looping without spanning tree ?

Which router and module? It likely is running stp, but not necessarily telling you it is. My 2951 with various modules is running spanning-tree, 'tho there's nothing really to configure. (I'm not digging out the 1720 to see what the WIC-4ESW says.)

Please add the make, models and configurations of your devices (in text format, using the editor's {} preformat option). Note that for a device to be on topic here the vendor needs to offer optional, paid support, see the [help/on-topic].

The switch modules in routers are limited in features. For example, you cannot do port channels.

How do you know that STP is not running on the 4221? To what VLAN are the module's interfaces 1 and 2 assigned to? To what VLAN are the two switch's interfaces assigned to?

From the Cisco 4-Port and 8-Port Layer 2 Gigabit EtherSwitch Network Interface Module Configuration Guide for Cisco 4000 Series ISR (emphasis mine):

Cisco 4-Ports and 8-Ports Layer 2 Gigabit EtherSwitch Network Interface Modules use STP (the IEEE 802.1D bridge protocol) on all VLANs. By default, a single instance of STP runs on each configured VLAN (provided you do not manually disable STP). You can enable and disable STP on a per-VLAN basis.
Cisco 4-Ports and 8-Ports Layer 2 Gigabit EtherSwitch Network Interface Modules support the following three STP:

Multiple Spanning Tree protocol
Per-VLAN Spanning Tree+
Rapid Per-VLAN Spanning Tree+


https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/interfaces/NIM/software/configuration/guide/4_8PortGENIM.html#pgfId-1097411
